# World of Warcraft Stuck at Connecting

Tags: games

I just got Linux and transfered my WoW folder from the Windows part of my HDD to the new Linux one. I have a problem while trying to play:

-I manage to start up the game (using Wine) but it stops at "Connecting".

Could anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the [winehq database](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1922)? Best bet when it comes to games is to reinstall, and also there aren't officially any bugs reported of this nature, but then again it haven't been rated yet (11.10).

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the Cache, WTF and Interface folders in the WoW folder to start with fresh configuration and such. Especially if you play it on an entirely new OS (which isn't even officially supported), it is normally better to start of with a default installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Yet I can only provide a workaround.

This issue only occurs if you are trying to start WoW in opengl mode via Battle.net launcher. In Directx mode it's way too slow.

The workaround is to start it using the wow-64.exe directly. So use the launcher only for getting the updates.